# Can someone travel on my passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, esta, fraud

I applied for an ESTA to travel to America and it was declined, no reason was given.

After all research I came to know that someone has been traveling on my passport since 2015. So I'd like to know who to contact about this.

Comment: What is your citizenship? How did you find out about this? Where did they supposedly travel to? Was that really with the same passport number or was it just someone with the same name?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the police and your country’s passport-issuing office?

Comment: How did you find out about this? What was the "research" you did?

Comment: "someone has been traveling on my passport since 2015": who has had access to your passport during that time?

Comment: Do you mean someone else travelled on a forged passport bearing your name and other personal details? Or someone stole your actual passport and used it to travel?

Answer (score 13):

**Not legally, no.**

If someone has been really "travelling on your passport" it can only be because they have a forged passport with the same name and number as yours.

You should report this to police in your country, and also tell your own passport authorities. Unfortunately you may find you have trouble because it will be hard to distinguish between you traveling on your passport and someone else doing it. You should maybe consult a lawyer.

However you haven't explained what research you have done to explain why you think someone is "traveling on your passport". It is going to be very difficult to convince immigration officials that the person who traveled with your name and passport number wasn't you.

Comment: There is always a trail to follow, money trail. But it would be difficult as that involves airlines, their payment gateway, banks etc. which maybe in different countries all operate under different laws.

Comment: Most likely your passport will be cancelled immediately (for both you and your clone); you may then have trouble re-applying (e.g. have to provide additional proofs of identity). I would hope it will be easy enough for you to prove your identity and the police to spot the fraud, by you providing proofs of identity and them looking at the patterns of travel (cloned passports will probably not be used in your home country but far away where the fraud is less likely to be spotted). The police may also want to interview you. But police and passport authorities will have procedures for it.